# how can I assign a function to button from anothor python script in tkinter?

Tags: python, function, user-interface, button, tkinter

I am trying to make a very simple GUI with tkinter to operate my python script and what I want to do is to read image files from a folder using a button and after that I want to name this image like "image1" to use in my functions. In my script I have decide() and convert to grayscale() functions which take image as input and make something. How can I proceed this algorithm? my GUI script is that I wrote up to now is below.
I created 4 buttons. "import image" is to select image file from the folder. "decide" button needs decide(image) argument and I dont know how can I combine these.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog 

window = Tk()

window.title("Welcome to LikeGeeks app")

window.geometry('350x200')
def close_window(): 
    window.destroy()

def open_image():
    pil_image = Image.open(filedialog.askopenfilename())

#in btn1 when I click button a folder is opening and I can chose image file, but I cant do anything that I explaned above.
btn1 = Button(window, text="Import Image")
btn1.config( height = 2, width = 15,command=open_image)
btn1.grid(column=0, row=0)


btn2 = Button(window, background = 'white', foreground = 'black', text="exit")
btn2.config( height = 2, width = 15, command = close_window)
btn2.grid(column=0, row=3)

btn3 = Button(window, text=" decide")
btn3.config( height = 2, width = 15 , command = quit)
btn3.grid(column=0, row=2)

btn4 = Button(window, text=" convert gray scale")
btn4.config( height = 2, width = 15 )
btn4.grid(column=0, row=1)



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This feels a lot like you want someone to help with a complete design. You  will probably not get much traction with this. Break your problem down into pieces and then if you run into problems ask about that focused problem. If this is not the case, it's hard to discern the actual question here. Maybe you can [edit] the question and make it clear what specific problem you have.

Comment: Its is a little unclear as to what you are trying to accomplish. Please break down you question into separate questions as it is clear you have more than one problem here. Please provide enough context to understand the goal.